# Reset/clear Part with \backmatter in a customized book.cls?

Tags: sectioning, bookmarks, book-design, documentclass-writing, parts

I'm producing a fairly large volume using a customized version of `book.cls` with four Parts containing several chapters in `\mainmatter`, followed by a `\backmatter` that contains only the Bibliography for the whole volume (no appendices or index).

What I'm finding is that the running header of the last chapter & section is running through the `\backmatter` bibliography? I didn't have that problem with volumes that don't have parts and guess that the `\chapter*` assignment in the bibliography environment definition supplanted the prior chapter/section, but it seems that the `\part` is somehow getting in the way.

In a (most likely) related problem, the bookmark set by `hyperref` shows the `\backmatter` Bibliography being included (i.e. a chapter within) in the last Part.

Is there a way to test for and reset the depth in the `\backmatter` definition, both for the header and `hyperref`?

Comment: Well, modifying classes is  to be avoided most times. Without any code at hand I would say `\cleardoublepage\markboth{}{}` before `\backmatter` but this is only a guess. I don't think that `hyperref` has to do with the problem here. Please provide the minimal document that produces this issue!

Comment: It's a custom `.cls` based largely on on `book.cls`... both `\backmatter` and `\def\ps@headings` have been left unchanged so far (customizations are mainly format and layout particulars).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer -- seems to me (after double checking) that both `book` and `amsbook` have a much too minimal approach to what should be set with `\backmatter`.  i'm putting a note into the ams-latex bugs/requests list to take a look at this, with reference to this question and comment.  thanks for the idea.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Huh???? I don't know what you're talking about

Comment: Thanks @barbarabeeton ... I've been searching all over and have seen a couple references to some such issues with `\backmatter` without any real solutions or workarounds found.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, the same issue apparently occurs using the stock `book.cls` as well, which is why I'm having the problem in my customized version. I've seen references to similar problems with `\appendix` and `\backmatter` carrying through `\markboth` when parts are used.

Comment: @Scard: Actually, I doubt the usefulness of those `\....matter` commands in general . Perhaps you can drop them

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, too late in the production game to make that kind of structural change, unfortunately... would need too much additional coding to get the volume into the required layout. A number of formatting switches are set in the class based on `\if@mainmatter` etc.

Comment: @Scard: Can you post the smallest possible document that has this issue. I'll see what's possible then

Comment: @Scard -- one problem noticed here with `amsbook` is that in the toc, biblio and index are subsumed under the last part; that's probably what you mean by the `hyperref` reference.  one workaround i've considered is to treat the toclevel of any `\chapter*` element in the backmatter the same as a part, but i don't have working code.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, that sounds like the same problem... as a temp workaround, is there some way to insert something into the `\backmatter` definition that would test if `\value{part}>0` and issue a "phantom" part or otherwise increment the part counter in a way that might chuck it back to the same depth?? I don't want to use `\part*{}` so as not to have any output...

Comment: @Scard -- i intend to test possibilities, but don't have a good experimental file at the moment.  also, `amsbook` works differently from `book`, and that's the one i have to solve the problem for.  if i come up with something soon, i will share it, but i've got some other priorities higher on my to-do list at the moment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, understandable... I'm working on a dropdead deadline on this one myself... thus my slight panic - trying to find a quick workaround on this and two other smaller issues by tomorrow morning  :)

Comment: Found a partial workaround for now... actually it's partly using something from another question answered by @ChristianHupfer to fix the bookmark level in the pdf at least (added `\ifnum \value{part}>\m@ne \renewcommand{\toclevel@chapter}{-1} \fi` to the `\backmatter` definition), and just set frontmatter and backmatter pagestyle to `plain`... does what I need for now at least. I'll work on something more robust once thsi current deadline passes... now on to "chapter authors" and separate lists for authors and contributing authors on the titlepage...

Comment: how do you add your bibliography? can you add a MWE?

Comment: @Scard: To which answer by me do you refer?

Comment: 1) using `book.cls` I don't have problem of heading, well your question is not clear for me. 2) for bookmarks you can try `\backmatter
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}` from `bookmark` package.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, it was an answer to [Change bookmark depth](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199500/change-bookmark-depth)

Comment: @touhami, I'll see if I can put up an MWE soon... a bit swamped at the moment with post-holiday catch up work. The issue seems to only appear if there are parts set in the `mainmatter` structure, in which any chapters in `backmatter` retain the header/footer marks of the last mainmatter content. As a secondary issue, `hyperref` then also places them hierarchically within the last part set instead of as a base-level bookmark. `\backmatter` should, one would think, be resetting that hierarchy but doesn't.