# Change level in pdf outline

Tags: pdf

I am writing a memoir with a lot of chapters using the `memoir` class.

When generating the pdf, everything works perfectly fine except for the outline of the document.

In the following example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents


\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\blindtext

\part{First part}

\chapter{At first}

\Blindtext

\chapter{Then}

\Blindtext

\part{Second part}

\chapter{Second first}

\Blindtext

\chapter{Then again}

\blindtext

\chapter{General conclusion}

\appendix

\part*{Appendix}
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}

\chapter{First appendix}

\Blindtext

\chapter{Another important appendix}

\backmatter


\chapter{Bibliographie}

\blindtext

\chapter{Glossary}

\blinditemize


\end{document}
```

(bibliography and glossary are of course managed with adequate packages)

I get the following outline:

- Table of contents
- Introduction
- First part

  - At first
  - Then
- Second part

  - Second first
  - Then again
  - General conclusion
- Appendix

  - First appendix
  - Another important appendix
  - Bibliography
  - Glossary

While I'd like to have:

- Table of contents
- Introduction
- First part

  - At first
  - Then
- Second part

  - Second first
  - Then again
- General conclusion
- Appendix

  - First appendix
  - Another important appendix
- Bibliography
- Glossary

Comment: Could you please clarify: What does "outline" refer to? The table of contents or the pdf bookmarks? If it refers to the latter, you might be interested in this answer to [Change bookmark depth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199511/134144)

Comment: Exactly, thanks. I didn't know about bookmarks! Should I answer my own question? (I'm a newbie around here).
I used `\bookmarksetupnext{level=part}` with the `bookmark` package right before `\chapter`.

Comment: Or simply remove the question!

Comment: Instead of deleting your well written question, I'd suggest to close yours as a duplicate to the ine I linked to in my previous comment. Would you agree?

Comment: Alright. It even works with commands such as `\printbibliography` and `\printglossaries`. Thanks again.