# Removing chapter without causing warnings

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, chapters

I have the following format:

```
\part{X}
\section{foo}
\section{bar}
\subsection{foobar}
```

I don't want any chapters. Unfortunately, `hyperref` is throwing warnings over this. How can I either make `hyperref` ignore the missing chapters or include them in a way so they are not showing up in the PDF?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{MWE}
\author{Andrew Yang}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\part{Test}
\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which documentclass are you using? Can you please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), complete from `\documentclass` till `\end{document}`, that reproduces this warning?

Comment: @Tiuri I edited it in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete warning is:

> Package hyperref Warning: Difference (2) between bookmark levels is greater
>   (hyperref) than one, level fixed on input line 14.

When `hyperref` creates the bookmarks, it orders them hierarchically to display them in a tree-structure. In the default scheme, `\part` creates a bookmark at level -1, `\chapter` at level 0, `\section` at level 1, and so on. The warning tells you that by not having any `\chapter`, there is a gap in the bookmark levels.

I borrowed from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199508/103046) to redefine the levels such that `\section` creates a bookmark at level 0 (the level of `\chapter`), and so on. With that, the warning disappears.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{MWE}
\author{Andrew Yang}
\date{\today}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\toclevel@section}{0}
\renewcommand{\toclevel@subsection}{1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\part{Test}
\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using the `report` class within which chapters are an integral element. Is there any reason not to use the `article` class?

As a different approach you could use the `memoir` class with the `article` option

```
\documentclass[article, ...]{memoir}
\begin{document}
\part{A part}
\chapter{Typeset as a section}
\section{Typeset as a subsection}
...
\end{document}
```

which makes a chapter appear as a section, a section appear as a subsection, and so on. If later on you decide that you do want `\chapter` to be typeset as a chapter, just delete the `article` option.

**Note:** In the `report` class section number are preceeded by the chapter number; if you don't use chapters in the class then you will probably want to change the section numbering. Just another complication.